# Viewport in blender 2.8 is all black. No problems with 2.79b

Tags: 3d-view

I downloaded and installed blender 2.8. But the viewport isn't working properly. Instead of displaying the objects, the grid, all I get is a black void. I don't have a clue what the problem could be. [image]

Comment: Had the same issue. For me the solution was to update my graphics card driver